# How to return multiple views in a Laravel controller?

Tags: php, laravel, view, controller, return

Inside a controller in Laravel I have this:

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::orderBy('name', 'asc')->paginate(13);
    $users2 = User::all();

    return view('contatos.index')->with('users', $users);
    return view('auth.register')->with('users', $users2);
}
```

I know isn't right, it's just to demonstrate my logic. Is there a way to unite these two returns in a single return? Or even a much shorter form for this code?

Comment: What about return one of them and include another one in the one you are returning?

Comment: But how exactly do I do this inclusion?

Comment: It makes no sense to return 2 views. You should be returning 1 view, and include any subviews you need in that view.

Comment: @Mandy9019 I added an answer you can check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can include many views inside a single view using the `@include` directive:

`combined.blade.php`:

```html
@include('contatos.index')
@include('auth.register')
```

Then in your controller:

```php
public function index()
{
    $users = User::orderBy('name', 'asc')->paginate(13);
    $users2 = User::all();

    return view('combined')->with('users', $users);
}
```

There are many variants of `include`, like `includeWhen` of `includeIf`, they are all described in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#including-subviews

However, the key point to understand is that you always return only one thing (in your case, one view).

This view can be composed of multiple parts and this compositing job is the role of Blade.